# Ask python to tell me what version of ElementTree it's using

Tags: python, elementtree, canopy

I'm attempting to use ElementTree in Canopy / Python with the line:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

I'm looking in the Package Manager and can't tell how that xml gets included, but that's okay, because I'd like to be able to just print the version of ElementTree that's being used.

Is there some way to get this by typing

```
print ET.version
```

or

```
print ET.getVersion()
```

or something like that.  Those particular statements don't work.  But is there something similar that will work?

Comment: There's `ET.VERSION`. Using tab-completion in the interactive interpreter is handy for things like this. Or you can use `dir(ET)`. Of course, you do have to do the `import` first. :)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, Also the tab completion is handy.

Comment: @PM2Ring -very nice tab completion! thanks!